# VueTify : How to Override CSS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I want to override the css of a child vuetify component.

```css
.filterOPV > div > div {
  min-height: 30px !important;

}
.filterOPV > div > div > div  {
  background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
```

```
          <v-flex md2 class="filterOPV">
            <v-select
              :items="sortOPV"
              label="Filtre OPV"
              dense
              solo
            />
          </v-flex>
```

I tried the code above, but nothing changes.

I saw that some people were using Deep Selectors but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via two methods-

1. Using `::v-deep`

```
<style scoped>
.filterOPV ::v-deep .v-input__control {
    min-height: 30px !important;
}
.filterOPV ::v-deep .v-input__slot {
    background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
</style>
```

2. Using `>>>`

```
<style scoped>
.filterOPV >>> .v-input__control {
    min-height: 30px !important;
}
.filterOPV >>> .v-input__slot {
    background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
</style>
```

**Meaningful-**

`>>>` is identical to `::v-deep`. The basis for having these two ways is that when you are using pre-compilers, like SASS, they may have problems learning `>>>` and will fail to compile your CSS. If this occurs, switch to `::v-deep`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:deep` selector

```
<style scoped>
.filterOPV :deep(.v-input__control) {
  min-height: 30px !important;

}
.filterOPV :deep(.v-field)  {
  background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
</style>
```